# Who? What? Where?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

**WHO** did **WHAT**, and **WHERE**?

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PHILIP | CAUGHT A BIG C | LY |
| NADINE | DEEMED TIRAMI | WAY |
| MATTHEW | FELT THE TARM | YAK |
| PETE | FRETTED A LOT ABOUT C | EEK AGO |
| QUINN | HAD TO G | HIONERS |
| ERICA | NOW HOME MISSED H | NICALLY |
| GEORGE | ONLY HEARD OF STAR | TE CHANGE |
| FATIMA | PLAYED THE HARMONI | THE SEASIDE |
| PHUNTSOK | PRAYED FOR ALL HER | CK BENEATH HIM |
| ANNABEL | RESERVED TWO CANOES P | STLY OVERRATED |
| GRANT | SAW A F | PHAZARDLY AT BEST |
| ZANDER | SOBBED WHEN HER AGOU | ITTING UPON ITS EGG |
| FAYE | WORE A TUXE | W FOR THE PEDESTRIAN |

If you manage to square everything up correctly, you should be able to read off a hidden two-word phrase.

> **What is the hidden two-word phrase, and how do you derive it?**

Comment: Ah, finally the pleasure to see one of Stiv's puzzles without it already being answered.

Comment: Though I doubt I can solve it... :(

Comment: @Stevo you had almost 2.5 hours before Deusovi got it - what happened?

Comment: I went to bed. @TCooper

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may notice that the fragments

> can be fitted together. (The first list is alphabetized, and the second is sorted by length, so neither of them is the "correct" order yet - we'll have to rematch them)
>
>  SOBBED WHEN HER AGOU- looks likely to be AGOU**TI**, and you could finish this with **RAN A**WAY. And "PRAYED FOR HER" doesn't seem to need another word, but it would fit nicely if we changed HIONERS to **PARIS**HIONERS... hey, TIRANA and PARIS are both capital cities!

Doing this for all of them gives the following:

> [image: fragments rematched, each with a capital city re-added]
>
>  Now it's time to use the names. The easiest way to see how to do this is to notice that we have both QATAR and ZAMBIA's capitals, and the names QUINN and ZANDER are on the list...
>
>  In fact, *every* country has a name of the same length and initial letter. So we can use the list of people to reorder the actions taken.
>
>  [image: list reordered; people are associated with capitals]
>
>  And we can see reading down the first letters of the cities that this puzzle is about **WORLD CAPITALS**!

Comment: Perfect, well done :) Just in case that last step was a tad obscure I actually built in a second way to deduce it - rot13(gur ersrerapr gb 'fdhner rirelguvat hc' vf n abq gb gur snpg gung bapr pbeerpgyl nyvtarq, rirel fvatyr yvar unf gur fnzr ahzore bs yrggref - guvegl-guerr) - but you didn't need it. Nice solve.